# Why script in authentication flow is not allowed in newer versions of Keycloak

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I have tried enabling

```
Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled
```

but it is not showing script in provider list. Anybody know how to enable script ?

Comment: which Keycloak version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable scripts by creating file `profile.properties` in `/opt/keycloak/standalone/configuration/`
with contents

```
feature.scripts=enabled

feature.upload_scripts=enabled
```